# Cannot append new column to an existing MS database table from R using RODBC

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am trying to add a new column to a table extracted from a MS Access database (*.accdb) and save it back again to MS Access using sqlSave(), but R-Studio shows FATAL ERROR and restarts.

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library("RODBC")

conn <- odbcConnect("TEST01", believeNRows=FALSE)
Departments <- sqlQuery(conn, "select * from Departments")
Departments$New <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2)

sqlSave(conn, dat=Departments, 'Departments', append=FALSE, rownames=FALSE)
```

The program seems to encounter a problem and crushes after a few seconds.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RODBC sqlSave table creation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913616/rodbc-sqlsave-table-creation-problems)

Comment: Other possible (probably more relevant) [duplicate:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512259/)